# How effective is the Turbocharger for the Devotion LMG?

Tags: apex-legends

So the tooltip apparently states:

> Reduces autofire spin-up time for compatible weapons.

I have only had one match where I even found this hop-up for the LMG, but still couldn't find a Deovtion LMG anywhere to test it out.  It's a Legendary rarity hop-up so it's probably rare enough to not be found commonly.

I'm wondering how effective this attachment actually affects the Devotion LMG.  To start with, the gun already has a painfully long spool up time before max fire rate is reached, so I'm wondering if it's even worth getting this attachment when it means sticking with the Devotion long enough to hopefully find it through the course of the match.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Titanfall 2 had this "upgrade" as well. The effect was significant. I have no exact number, but I believe a reduction between 40%-60% was the result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very effective. I have found both the Devotion and the exotic (there is also a legendary one, which is less effective) attachment in several matches. It removes perhaps 90% of the spin up time, making the weapon extremely effective. It basically feels like it is firing at full speed right a trigger pull.

I would highly recommend using this if available.

The main problem when using the Devotion with the turbocharger is ammo since the fire rate is so high. Compounding this issue is that energy ammo can be hard to find. I would suggest having at least 100 rounds to feel safe using this, as running out of ammo is very easy with this attachment and has been the main problem I faced.